# Open Source Document Automation - Jinterview Alternative

Tags: documentation-generator

Is anybody aware of an open source document automation software like similar to jinterview: http://jinterview.sourceforge.net/default.htm

Jinterview was abandoned so long ago that I have been having trouble even getting it up and running and was looking for something like a spiritual successor that would generate documents based on an "interview".

The core need is simple: I would like an administrator-type user to be able to set up questionnaires or interviews that guide another user through a series of questions an ultimately generate a document from those results. I envision the setup of interviews being some way to set up various if statements and based on the answers different parts will be added to the resulting document or omitted. 
From the end user point of view, they will select the document type they are after and then be guided through the process. 
The overall goal is to use this for specification document generation where every individual project may not use all of the parts in the template, but having a single unified template where everything can be stored is much more expeditious than trying to keep a list of various templates and scraping them all together.

EDIT: Rather than a completed software package, could anybody maybe recommend a framework for document generation that would be manageable to build a tool around?  Something like a php framework that could be used to generate documents?

Comment: I regularly have been sent pdf documents with editable fields. Would this not suffice?

Comment: The intent of this is to be able to use a large template for different project aspects.  Depending on the needs of a given project, you can run through the "interview" and pare out the information that is unneeded and will be left with 90% of the work complete.  Editable pdf fields would be more akin to a form.